# How can i change php version in MAMP 5.3 to have php 5.5.38

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

So I exported an online Prestashop website to my local computer.

I'm using MAMP 5.3 and the website need PHP 5.5.38 to work correctly.

How can I change my PHP version to 5.5.38 in MAMP because I'm not able to find the folder in: /Applications/MAMP/bin/PHP

Looking for the folder to import in my php version of MAMP

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A simple Google search my answer your question. https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+mamp+folder+location+php+version&oq=mac+mamp+folder+location+php+version&aqs=chrome..69i57.4215j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: if you don't need anything special that only mamp provides, I'd recommend to use xampp or some docker setup

Comment: @ Raymond thanks for your lol answer but if i came here is because i dont found it on google :-) I have to mention that i'm looking the answer for MAMP and not for MAMP PRO

Comment: If you have already looked at specific documentation/tutorials/examples, it's always good to identify these and why they haven't helped, to save everyone's time and to make it clear that you have done some of your own research. Does this one (number 3 on search results from @Raymond's query) not help? https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/08/07/how-to-addchange-php-versions-appearing-in-mamp-preferences/ (obviously this does assume you have already installed the required php version - if you have, and it's somewhere else, you could try creating a directory link).

Comment: So what i did is install MAMP PRO demo version on another computer, and install the php 5.5.38 version i wanted.

Comment: Then i copied in my computer and that's was my workaround :-)

Comment: OK - please add an answer documenting your workaround, to make this question easier for future enquirers to use. I think it would be useful also if you explained why just installing php 5.5.38 direct (not via MAMP at all) wouldn't work, since I have to say that I was assuming you could just do that.